# Get element closest to the parent and include it inside - jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello I have been wrapping elements using jQuery, until now everything is ok but I get stuck trying to find the way to include the **< a class="pinterest-anchor"** into the **< div class="wrapMe"**.

For now I got this:

```
<div class="wrapPinImg">
    <a href="#" class="pinterest-anchor">
        <i class="fi-social-pinterest"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="wrapMe">
        <img src="img.png" class="wrapMe" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I need this (**Include** class:pinterest-anchor   **inside**   .wrapMKe):

```
<div class="wrapPinImg">
    <div class="wrapMe">
        <a href="#" class="pinterest-anchor">
            <i class="fi-social-pinterest"></i>
        </a>
        <img src="img.png" class="wrapMe" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The "more or less" code idea:

```
$(".wrapPinImg img").each(function() {
    $(this).parent(".wrapMe").closest("a").find(".pinterest-anchor").appendTo(".wrapMe");
});
```

/***************************************************************************/

to get a better idea about what I'm trying to do here is the whole thing:

```
/*HTML*/        
<div class="wrapPinImg">
            <a href="#" class="pinterest-anchor">
                <i class="fi-social-pinterest"></i>
            </a>
            <img src="img.png" class="wrapMe" />
        </div>
/*JQUERY*/    
    $(".wrapPinImg img").each(function() {
        var floatStyle = $(this).attr('style');
        $(this).attr('style', '');
        $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapMe"></div>');
        /* $(this).parent(".wrapMe").closest("a").find(".pinterest-anchor").appendTo(".wrapMe"); -- HERE THE PROBLEM*/
        $(this).parent(".wrapMe").attr('style', floatStyle );
    });
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next element and [prepend()](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to move the element into the next element (wrapMe)

```js
$('.pinterest-anchor').each(function(){
$(this).next().prepend($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapPinImg">
    <a href="#" class="pinterest-anchor">
        <i class="fi-social-pinterest"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="wrapMe">
        <img src="img.png" class="wrapMe" />
    </div>
</div>
```

or use instead of `next()` the `siblings()` function:

```js
$('.pinterest-anchor').each(function(){
$(this).siblings('.wrapMe').prepend($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapPinImg">
    <a href="#" class="pinterest-anchor">
        <i class="fi-social-pinterest"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="wrapMe">
        <img src="img.png" class="wrapMe" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .next works better, .siblings duplicate the <a link
Sorted, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `anchor` element and prepend it to its immediately following sibling.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".wrapPinImg > a.pinterest-anchor").each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).next(".wrapMe"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapPinImg">
  <a href="#" class="pinterest-anchor">
    <i class="fi-social-pinterest"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="wrapMe">
    <img src="img.png" class="wrapMe" />
  </div>
</div>
```

References

1. [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

   > Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.
2. [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependto/)

   > Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the beginning of the target.